# Proof of inner product

Tags: inner-products

Let $V$ be a vector space with inner product $\langle\,,\,\rangle$ and $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ an orthonormal basis of $V$. Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,v_i\rangle^2=\|x\|^2$, for $x\in V$.

I´m not very fond of proofs but this is what I have:

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,v_i\rangle^2
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (\|x\|\,\|v_i\| \cos(\theta))^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \|x\|^2 \|v_i\|^2 \cos^2(\theta)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (\|x\|^2\cos(\theta)) (\|v_i\|^2 \cos(\theta))\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x,x\rangle \langle v_i,v_i\rangle\\
&=\langle x,x\rangle\sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_i,v_i\rangle\\
&=\|x\|^2 n
\end{align}

What am I wrong? Any suggestions to improve my proofs would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You are wrong from the beginning, as the angle $\theta$ depends on $i$.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is this:
$$\|x\|^2\cos\theta \ \ne\ \langle x,x\rangle$$
Instead, we have $\langle x,x\rangle = \|x\|^2$ without the $\cos$ term.

And, **hint** for the solution: write $x=\xi_1 v_1+\xi_2 v_2+\dots$, then calculate $\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle$ by substituting this into the right argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the [Parseval's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_identity). Observe that since $(v_i)_{i=1}^n$ is an orthonormal basis,
$$ x = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_i,x \rangle v_i
$$
By Pythagorean Theorem,
$$ \|x\|^2 = \left\lVert \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_i,x \rangle v_i\right\rVert = \sum_{i=1}^n \|\langle v_i,x \rangle v_i\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |\langle v_i,x \rangle|^2
$$
The problem with your proof is it uses $\theta$, which is not very rigorous, and leads to the incorrect result.